# Given the following data pairs, find the interpolating polynomial of degree 3 and estimate the value of y corresponding to x = 1.5.

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation

So i was given this question

Given the following data pairs, find the interpolating polynomial of degree 3 and estimate the value of y corresponding to x = 1.5.

a) $(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 10)$

I have never seen such a question and there are no theorem's on how to go about it. I've seen a different example where they set up an equation like

$p(x)$ = $r_0$ + $r_1x$ + $r_2x^2$ + $r_3x^3$

I do not see how they came about this.

Comment: You are obviously missing some knowledge about the subject. Are you self learning? If so, what book are you using?

Comment: Yes im self learning, i'm using linear algebra with application textbook

Comment: By what author? What page?

Comment: keith nicholson

Comment: I also asked what page...

Answer (score 2):

This is  *Lagrange's interpolation polynomial*: given $n+1$ pairs $(x_k,y_k)_{0\le k\le n}$ of real numbers, it is the (unique) polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $\le n$ such that $p(x_k)=y_k$  for all $k=0,\dots n$. The solution easy to find with some linear alggebra, is 
$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n y_k\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\dots(x-x_{k-1})(x-x_{k+1})\dots(x-x_n)}{(x_k-x_0)(x_k-x_1)\dots (x_k-x_{k-1})  (x_k-x_{k+1})\dots(x_k-x_n)}$$
Hence in the present case, we have
\begin{align*}p(x)=0\cdot\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{-6}+2\cdot\frac{x(x-2)(x-3)}{2}\\{}+5\cdot\frac{x(x-1)(x-3)}{-2}+10\cdot\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{6}.\end{align*}

To efficiently compute the value of this polynomial at a given point $x$, you can use *Neville's algorithm*, along the following scheme:
$$\begin{matrix}
p_{00}(x)=y_0\\
&p_{01}(x)=\dfrac{(x_0-x)p_{10}(x)+(x-x_1)p_{00}(x)}{x_0-x_1} \\
p_{10}(x)=y_1&&p_{02}(x)=\dfrac{(x_0-x)p_{11}(x)+(x-x_2)p_{01}(x)}{x_0-x_2} \\
&p_{11}(x)=\dfrac{(x_1-x)p_{20}(x)+(x-x_2)p_{10}(x)}{x_1-x_2} \\
p_{20}(x)=y_2&& p_{12}(x)=\dfrac{(x_1-x)p_{21}(x)+(x-x_3)p_{11}(x)}{x_1-x_3} \\\\
&p_{21}(x)=\dfrac{(x_2-x)p_{30}(x)+(x-x_3)p_{20}(x)}{x_2-x_3} \\
p_{30}(x)=y_3
\end{matrix}$$
and finally
$$ p_{03}(x)=\frac{(x_0-x)p_{12}(x)+(x-x_3)p_{02}(x)}{x_0-x_3}. $$

Answer (score 1):

use the Lagrange interpolating formula as follow
$$y=L_0y_0+L_1y_1+L_2y_2+L_3y_3$$
so that 
$$L_0=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)(x_0-x_3)}$$
$$L_1=\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)}$$
$$L_2=\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}$$ 
$$L_3=\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3-x_0)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}$$
$x_0=0,x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3=3,y_0=1,y_1=2,y_2=5,y_3=10$

then plug $x=1.5$

Comment: So you would plug the values in the 4 formulas, then plug it in the top formula?

Comment: @Micky yes as you said

Comment: How would i know which values to pick for x, x0, x1 , x2, x3? would it be 1,2,5,10?

Comment: @Micky $x=0,1,2,3$ ............

Comment: @Micky If you do not understand what Lagrange's formulas are, then I don't think it's a good idea for you to simply use them with no actual understanding. If you use them that way, you are not learning linear algebra, you are learning how to plug numbers into a formula.

Answer (score 0):

The interpolating polynomial has the shape

$$p(x) = r_0 + r_1x + r_2 x^2 + r_3x^3$$

Also, the interpolating polynomial has the following properties:

$$p(0)=1\\
p(1)=2\\
p(2)=5\\
p(3)=10$$